# Equality in Local LYM

Tags: combinatorics

The Local LYM inequality says the following : for all $A \subseteq [n]^{(r)}$,
$$ \frac{|\partial A|}{\binom{n}{r-1}} \geq \frac{|A|}{\binom{n}{r}},$$
where $\partial A$ is the lower shadow of $A$ and $[n]^{(r)}$ is the collection of all subsets of $\{1, ..., n\}$ having exactly $r$ elements.

When do we have equality in local LYM ?

It's clear that we have equality if $A = \emptyset$ and $A = [n]^{(r)}$ and I feel that we the only other case for which we have equality is $A = [n]^{(r)}$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[n-(r-1)]\cdot|\partial \mathcal {A}|  \geqslant r \cdot |\mathcal {A}|$

But if we have here an equality then for every $B \in \partial \mathcal {A}$ then all $[n-(r-1)]$ sets (*r-sets*) obtained by adding an element to $B$ must be in $\mathcal {A}$. Otherwise it will be a strict inequality.

From $\partial \mathcal {A}$ goes $[n-(r-1)]\cdot|\partial \mathcal {A}|$ arrows towards $\mathcal {A}$ ... that is $[n-(r-1)]$ arrows for each $B \in \partial \mathcal {A}$. So we obtain all $[n-(r-1)]$ r-sets like this $B \cup \{i\} $  (... having $i \in [n] - B$)

That's the way the arrows are counted, from $\mathcal \partial {A}$ to $\mathcal {A}$.

From $\mathcal {A}$  to $\partial \mathcal {A}$ is simple, and we have $r \cdot |\mathcal{A}|$ arrows. The equality implies the same arrows (the directions only having changed). The importance is practically given to the arrows !!...

---

P.S.
[image: Local LYM Photo]

Answer (score 1):

[image: LYM inequality - Photo 1]

[image: LYM inequality - Photo 2]

You could also use this simple Link on Wikipedia :
[Lubell–Yamamoto–Meshalkin inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubell%E2%80%93Yamamoto%E2%80%93Meshalkin_inequality)

Comment: I don't see why equality implies that for every $B\in \mathcal{B} $ every $r$-set containing $B$ is in $\mathcal {A}$.

Comment: I'll write an answer below, because the *Comment* is too long, too many characters.

Comment: The answer's gone above now ! ...
Well, I'm a beginner too on stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Do you happen to recall the source for your solution? It seems to be a screenshot of a textbook. I am using this as a reference for something I am working on and would like to cite it.